# Installshield limited version for the project migration VS2010 to VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installshield, visual-studio-2017

I had VS2010 application along with the Installshield limited edition installer. I did migrate the project from VS2010 to vS2017, my other application got converted fine. But the install shield project was unable to connect to convert to 2017. The Visual studio enterprise is installed on my machine. Let us know if I need to apply any patches to installshield limited edition.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield Limited Edition is not available in Visual Studio 2017. Our group had to buy a license for InstallShield Express when we migrated our project to VS2017.